# jQuery selectors : list not inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, cheerio

I have an HTML structure like the following :

```
<div id='main'>
  <ul>
    <li>1_1</li>
    <li>1_2</li>
    <li>1_3</li>
  </ul>
   <ul>
    <li>2_1</li>
    <li>2_2</li>
    <li>2_3</li>
  </ul>
  <div id='sub1'>
    <ul>
      <li>sub1_1</li>
      <li>sub1_2</li>
      <li>sub1_3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

- Using jQuery, I am trying to get the text of **ALL the li** elements **in ALL the ul** inside the 'main' div, but **NOT in 'sub1'** div.
- '#main' can contain a single list, or many, or none.
- Bonus if the selectors work with cheerio on Node.js, but all I really would like is to learn the right way to solve that problem :)
- I can add my failed attempts if anyone feels like this post needs it. To avoid tl;dr, let's just say I have an OK knowledge of jQuery and nothing I've tried worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `child selector` and after that go for the `descendants`,

```
$("#main > ul li")
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/Z4YeX/)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out elements, that you do not need using Jquery filters, one of them is the "NOT" filter.
Use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#main > ul li").not("#sub1").each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());

});
});
```

Happy Coding :)